# How to copy windows servers 2008 domain users to 2012 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, window-server-2012

How to move new server with all current users?
I have windows server 2008r2 then I have to move to new server with 2012. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Join the new server to the domain. Make it a Domain Controller. Done.